# Why is my view created in my user schema?

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2014, database-schema

I'm using MSSQL Studio and am connected to a SQL Server 2014 with my windows credentials (DOMAIN\user).

I just created a new view and wondered why another user could not find it:

```
CREATE VIEW abc AS SELECT 1 AS a
```

Unexpectedly this view was not created in `dbo` schema but in `DOMAIN\user`.
To create the view in `dbo` schema I needed to execute:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.abc AS SELECT 1 AS a
```

This kind of surprises me, for I've been creating views for ages without explicit schema and have always been created in `dbo` – since today.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Your SQL Server login will be mapped to a user in the database. What is the default schema for the database user?

Comment: Security > Users > {user}   right-click - Properties > General ... Default Schema

Comment: or simply add the schema   CREATE VIEW dbo.abc AS SELECT 1 AS a

Comment: @Richard and @John, you are both right: The default schema for my user was `DOMAIN\user` instead of `dbo`. I fixed that and now all is fine again.
Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check under Security -> Login -> Your User - User Mapping. For all selected maps your "Default Schema" should be changed to dbo.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your default schema to dbo, but as a best practice views should be scripted to include the schema.  In the case of dbo, it's 4 extra characters with the period but it prevents these types of issues.